# Datatables markup code only partially working for the current page

Tags: jquery, datatables

This code is partially working.  It correctly changes every single input box within the table, but I also need the `.change()` event called on it so it correctly does some math to other parts.

This change() event is working but only on the current page of the datatables.  I move to other pages and the math isn't being calculated.

```
table.on('dblclick', '[name="markupControl"]', function () {
            var value = parseFloat($(this).val()).toFixed(2);

            table.api().column(7).nodes().to$().find('input').val(value).change();

        });
```

When ever they double click on an input box it needs to change the markup value of all other input boxes and then it needs to call the change event which applies some math to make sure everything adds up for the other input boxes.  Below is the change event it should be firing.

```
table.on('change', '[name="markupControl"]', function () {
            // Get the rate id from this element
            var rateid = $(this).data('rateid');

            // Pricing variables
            var cost = parseFloat($('div[name="costControl"][data-rateid="' + rateid + '"]').text().replace("$", '').replace(",", ''));
            var markup = parseFloat($(this).val());

            // Update the Retail price for the correct plan retail box
            var retailControl = $('input[name="retailControl"][data-rateid="' + rateid + '"]');
            var newRetail = parseFloat(cost + markup).toFixed(2);
            retailControl.val(newRetail);

            // Force this control to go back to 2 decimals
            $(this).val(markup.toFixed(2));

            // Needed for later so we can call the change event on the retail control
            retailControl.change();
        });
```

I'm assuming the `.change()` event is not being fired for input boxes on other pages with the double click.  Not sure what I am missing to make this work.

EDIT:

Here is a jsfiddle representing my issue.  Change any Markup column, then double click in that input box, you'll see it all works until you switch to the next page.

https://jsfiddle.net/jamesjw007/hvk30q5w/

Comment: The change() event would be triggered on whatever it finds with find('input'), but the event listener is looking for a change on '[name="markupControl"]'. Are those different things?

Comment: @Adam the name="markupControl" is the input box.  It all works perfectly for the page I am looking at.  But when I switch pages, the value are changed, but the math doesn't add up like it does correctly on the page I am looking at.

Comment: @Adam Iadded a jsfiddle that shows an example of my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't 100% follow what the intention of the code is to suggest exactly how to modify it, but I think the root of the problem is that the jquery selectors will only get return things present in the DOM. Datatables is updating the DOM on the fly, so the only items your jquery selectors will find are those that exist on the current page. If you want to update the data on items that are not being displayed, you will want to use the [data()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells().data()) method.

Since you want to update every cell that you are matching, you could use the [rows().every()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/cells().every()) method, then set the data on the cell for each item.

Also, make sure to call the [draw()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()) method when you are finished or your results won't display.

Comment: `table.api().column(7).nodes().to$().find('input').val(value).change();` This line successfully updates every single Markup Input Controller even on the hidden pages.  It just seems the .change() gets left off anything not on the current page.  Not sure if that helps or not.

Comment: Yeah, which is probably for similar reasons. There's only the 10 items that exist in the DOM that can be triggered, so those are the ones that update